# Pivot n times for Select statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

```
DECLARE 
    @StartDate  DATE,
    @EndDate    DATE,
    @NumMonths INT,

SET @NumMonths = 12
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(m, -@NumMonths, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))


SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SignUpDate) RowNum, SignUpDate,
        TotalSignUp / TotalSignUp M1,
        --M2 / TotalSignUp M2,
        --M3 / TotalSignUp M3,
        --M4 / TotalSignUp M4,
        --M5 / TotalSignUp M5,
        --M6 / TotalSignUp M6,
        --M7 / TotalSignUp M7,
        --M8 / TotalSignUp M8,
        --M9 / TotalSignUp M9,
        --M10 / TotalSignUp M10,
        --M11 / TotalSignUp M11,
        --M12 / TotalSignUp M12
    FROM (
        SELECT SignUpDate, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT ClientID) TotalSignUp,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M2,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 2, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 3, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M4,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 4, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M5,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 5, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M6,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 6, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M7,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 7, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M8,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 8, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M9,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 9, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M10,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 10, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M11,
            SUM(CASE WHEN MonthActive = DATEADD(m, 11, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @StartDate), 0)) THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) M12
```

How can I perform a loop for the select statement so that I can dynamically produce the number of M select statements as set by the @numMonths variable?

e.g., I will want the user of the report to be able to select the @numMonths as an input variable and they could say, want to go back 6 months, or 24 months. I would want the select statement to  dynamically pivot in a loop depending on what the @numMonths value is.

To put it in other words I don't want to type out M1-M36 36 times just in case the user wants to go back 3 years, that will look so messy. I want a 1 line 'template' and a Counter + 1 until it reaches the number of @numMonths

Comment: The better question is, why do you want to use a loop at all; SQL is a set-based language so you should really be using a set-based solution.

Comment: I just assumed it had to be a loop. E.g. I don't want to type out M1-M36 36 times just in case the user wants to go back 3 years, that will look so messy. I want a 1 line 'template' and a Counter + 1 until it reaches the number of @numMonths

Comment: No, when writing T-SQL (or SQL), looping is likely the *last* thing you want to do. Seems like what you want here is conditional aggregation or a `PIVOT`. though difficult to confirm based on  the incomplete statement and lack of sample data and expected results.

Comment: Yes, looks like you want to group your data by month and then pivot the grouped rows to columns. The problem is, if you want the number of months to vary then you'll end up with a result that has a variable number of columns which sounds awkward.

Comment: Variable number of columns is actually the desired result as it's a Churn report. Just need to know how to do the pivot. Instead of type out 36 lines M1-M36

Comment: If you always need 36 columns, then writing those out is the best method.

Comment: @AndyO'Rourke, can you post sample data and expected results? Thanks!

Comment: @Zhorov - thanks, I've uploaded to Github some sample data as well as the full SQL. There's pretty much 3 pivots to do but I figured if I can do 1 I can work out the others https://github.com/Drewbty/PivotQuerySQL.git

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##TimePeriods
GO
DECLARE 
@StartDate  DATE,
@EndDate    DATE,
@NumMonths INT,
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @NumMonths = 5
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(m, -@NumMonths, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(m, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

;WITH TimePeriods AS 
(
  SELECT @StartDate AS TheDate
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(m,1,TheDate) FROM TimePeriods
  WHERE TheDate < @EndDate
)
SELECT * INTO ##TimePeriods FROM TimePeriods

DECLARE @ColList VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @ColList = STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(TheDate),',')
FROM ##TimePeriods

SET @SQL = 
'
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
SELECT 1 AS TheData, * 
FROM ##TimePeriods
-- JOIN YOUR DATA IN HERE
) SourceData
PIVOT 
(MAX(TheData)
FOR TheDate IN ('+@ColList+')
)
AS PivotTable
'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Comment: Maybe this is correct but the query has been changed too much to the point where I can't follow or understand it. Hopefully it helps someone else